# emacs: put S-Expression to kill ring without removing it

Tags: emacs, copy-paste, kill-ring

I'm looking for a command to put an S-expression to the kill ring, without removing it.

The following scenario would do the thing, however the expression would be removed, when using `M-x kill-sexp`:

```
(foo (bar bam))
^
point here
```

Comment: `C-M-SPC` + `M-w` should work.

Answer (score 5):

There is no single chord, but you can do two:

- both <kbd>C-M-SPC</kbd> and <kbd>C-M-@</kbd> run the command [`mark-sexp`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Marking-Objects.html)
- <kbd>M-w</kbd> runs the command [`kill-ring-save`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Other-Kill-Commands.html)

Alternatively, you can do

- <kbd>C-M-k</kbd> runs the command [`kill-sexp`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Expressions.html)
- <kbd>C-/</kbd> runs the command [`undo`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Undo.html)

If your buffer is read-only, the first command will fail, but the
S-expression will still be copied into the [`kill-ring`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Kill-Ring.html).

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this (e.g. with the built-in `thing-at-point`, or just calling `kill-sexp` via `call-interactively` and restoring the original buffer contents after).

It's pretty straightforward to implement as a slightly modified `kill-sexp` though. This is what I use:

```
(defun copy-sexp-as-kill (&optional arg)
  "Save the sexp following point to the kill ring.
ARG has the same meaning as for `kill-sexp'."
  (interactive "p")
  (save-excursion
    (let ((orig-point (point)))
      (forward-sexp (or arg 1))
      (kill-ring-save orig-point (point)))))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-K") #'copy-sexp-as-kill)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend installing [smartparens](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens) then simply using `sp-copy-sexp`.